# ASP SessionState in SQL Server mode throws up

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I'm trying to install a web application. The app works fine for the first two pages and then starts throwing up the serialization error as below. Everything works fine when I change the `sessionState` mode to `InProc`. However it throws up when the mode is `SQLServer`

> *Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.*

Further I know for a reason that it's not an application issue because the app installation works fine when installed on other boxes. Could there be any other environment/configuration issues due to which this happens?

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It works on other boxes using SQLServer as a state server?  It sounds like you are trying to store an unserializable object which should fail on ALL boxes using SQLServer as a state server.

Comment: yes, it works on other boxes with SQLServer as the session state ! That's the fishy bit .

Comment: You may want to check your installations.  You may think you have the same code on each server, but it might be in an incorrect directory or never have been copied.  You could add a small label filled in by code behind to the page in question, redeploy and check to make sure that each server is executing the same code/pages.  Also, is the version of IIS the same, with the same settings, on each machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was something else entirely. We had installed Dynatrace on that environment for measuring performance of the Application and it was screwing around with the session state once turned on !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deploying on different machines, each must have it's own `web.config` file.  I would guess on the machine in question, the web.config settings may not be correct.

Comment: no I've ensured that the web.config settings are the same in all the boxes.

Comment: So all the boxes are sharing the same SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, all the boxes are sharing the same SQL server